# Calling a test method in another TestClass

Tags: python, automation, webdriver

Hi I have the following test classes
logintests.py:

```
 class SignOnTests(BaseTest): 
     def test_login_info(self):
        #some code
```

passwordtests.py:

```
class ResetPasswordTests(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_mytest(self):
      #somecode
      #Should Call SignOnTests.test_login_info()
```

I've tried putting on passwordtests.py:
from logintests import SignOnTests
But keep gettingTypeError: unbound method test_login_info() must be called with SignOnTests instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Is it possible to call a test method within another module?

Comment: Are you trying to call test_login_info() statically? Like are you calling it on an instance of SignOnTests or are you calling it like SignOnTests.test_login_info()

Comment: I think its bad practice to have a unittest that depends on another unittest.  Not sure why you want to call it.  Looks like there is setup that is being done in that you want to reuse `test_login_info`, either you can see if the unittest library has something similar to https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html or create a derived class with `setUp`.